# runtime error with malloc

Tags: c, malloc, runtime-error

`#define MAXL 256`

I think the problem with my code is that eventho `numInput = 3`, somehow, `output[2]` did not exist so that when I try to assign it, the program crash (just guessing).

Is there a way to check if `ouput[2]` exist? or maybe someone will be able to find out the real problem of my code, that would be awesome!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

NOTE: The reason that I cast malloc is that it is expected by my lecturer.

```
Input strings are: 25 7 * 14 - 6 +
                   1 24 3 + * 41 -
                   2 37 4 + * 15 +

void processPostfixExp(const char * fileName)
{
    char ** input = NULL;
    double ** output = NULL;
    int i = 0, numInput = 0;
    char tempInput[MAXL] = {0};
    FILE * pFile = NULL;

    /* Get number of strings, check if file is readable and open file */    
    numInput = checkFile(fileName);
    pFile = fopen(fileName, "r"); 

    /* Allocate memory for the string storages and alert if fail */
    input = (char**)malloc(numInput * sizeof(char*));
    output = (double**)malloc(numInput * sizeof(double*));
    if(!input || !output)
    {
        printf("Memory allocation failed.\n");
        system("PAUSE");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Scan the file by lines and duplicate the string to input storage */
    for(i = 0; i < numInput; ++i)
    {
        fgets(tempInput, MAXL, pFile);
        tempInput[strlen(tempInput)-1] = '\0';
        input[i] = strdup(tempInput);
        //printf("\n%s", input[i]);
    }

    /* Close file and clear screen */
    fclose(pFile);
    system("CLS");

    /* Call converter and display result */
    printf("-------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("\nPostfix expression evaluation:\n");
    for(i = 0; i < numInput; ++i) 
    {
        printf("input = %s", input[i]); /* i = 2 Printf SUCCESS */
        *output[i] = evaluatePost(input[i]); /* i = 2 CRASH HERE */
        /* I added a check at the top most of the evaluatePost(), program did not get to there */
        //printf("\nCase %d: %s\nResult:%.2f\n", i + 1, input[i], *output[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("-------------------------------------------------------\n");
}
```

UPDATE:

so I added these lines and can confirm that output[2] does not exist... how is that possible? Please help, Thank you!

```
for(i = 0; i < numInput; ++i)
    {
        *output[i] = (double)i;
        printf("output[%d] = %.1f\n", i, *output[i]);
    }
```

Comment: You're not allocating enough memory. You're allocating memory numputs * 4 (remember that char * is sizeof because it's just a pointer and pointers are generally only 4 bytes)

Comment: Standard warning: Do not cast `void *` as returned by `malloc` & friends. Tell your lecturer; he should read a more recent book than K&R.

Comment: @Olaf Hahah, maybe I'll tell him at the end of the semester. I'm very bad with the words and my first assignment was given a C because I did not follow set way.

Comment: I tutor myself and people like that add to the bad reputation of C and the next generation of bad style programmers.

Comment: when using malloc (and family of functions) 1) do not cast the returned value as it is already a void*, so can be assigned to any pointer  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful\

Comment: when using the fopen() function, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: what happens when checkfile() returns 0 or a negative number (indicating an error occurred)?

Comment: following this line: 'if(!input || !output)'  it may be that one of the proceeding malloc() operations was successful.  should check the status immediately after the call to malloc() .  Then to avoid a memory leak, the memory pointer(s) should be passed to free() to avoid a memory leak.   The error handling, (if performed immediately after the call to malloc()) would be best handled with a call to perror() as then the system error message would also be output on stderr.

Comment: regarding this line: 'tempInput[strlen(tempInput)-1] = '\0';'  It seems to be trying to replace a newline with a NUL byte.  however; on windows and DOS, the newline is two bytes so this line would fail to do the job.  Suggest char *offset = NULL;  if (NULL != (offset = strstr( tempInput, "\n") ) ) {*offset = '\0'; }   This is especially important when the last line in the file might not have a trailing newline

Comment: @user3629249 Thank you for your detailed instructions! I will try to implement this `char *offset = NULL; if (NULL != (offset = strstr( tempInput, "\n") ) ) {*offset = '\0'; }`

Comment: You have a pointer to an array of uninitialized pointers. Using the first pointer is fine (since it points to something). Using the pointers in the array is not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you have:

```
*output[i]
```

You have allocated `numInput` pointers to double, but the pointers themselves don't exist.

It looks like you want to allocate space not for pointers, but for doubles:

```
double *output;
…
output = (double*)malloc(numInput * sizeof(double));
```

Comment: Exactly, OP allocated memory to store pointers, but not for what they point to. I have a love/hate relationship with malloc because of that confusion.

Comment: Oh yes! Silly me. I had to change from the original idea and completely forgot about the purpose of `**output`. Thank you for pointing it out! I don't  think I would've ever because ideas in my head is very messy at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is wrong with your call to evaluatePost(), especially as you have not provided a prototype for that function.

However, overall, your code should look similar to the following:

in the future, please post code that (standalone) actually cleanly compiles
when you want help with a run time problem.

strongly suggest compiling with all warnings enabled.

For gcc, at a minimum, use '-Wall -Wextra -pedantic'

When handling a error, always cleanup allocated memory, open files, etc.

```
#define  _POSIX_C_SOURCE (200809L)
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // exit() and EXIT_FAILURE
#include <string.h> // memset() and strdup()

#define MAXL (256)

// prototypes
int     checkFile( const char * );
double  evaluatePost( char * );

void processPostfixExp(const char * fileName)
{
    char   **input = NULL;
    double **output = NULL;

    int    i = 0;
    int    numInput = 0;
    char   tempInput[MAXL] = {0};
    FILE   *pFile = NULL;

    /* Get number of strings, check if file is readable and open file */
    numInput = checkFile(fileName);
    if( NULL == (pFile = fopen(fileName, "r") ) )
    { // then fopen failed
        perror( "fopen for input file failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    /* Allocate memory for the string storages and alert if fail */
    if( NULL == (input = malloc(numInput * sizeof(char*)) ) )
    { // then malloc failed
        perror( "malloc for input failed" );
        fclose( pFile );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, malloc successful

    memset( input, 0x00, numInput*sizeof(char*) ); // to make later free() operation easy

    if( NULL == (output = malloc(numInput * sizeof(double*)) ) )
    { // then malloc failed
        perror( "malloc for output failed" );
        fclose( pFile );
        free( input );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, malloc successful

    memset( output, 0x00, numInput * sizeof(double*) ); // to make later free() operation easy

    /* Scan the file by lines and duplicate the string to input storage */
    for(i = 0; i < numInput; ++i)
    {
        if( NULL == fgets(tempInput, MAXL, pFile) )
        { // then fgets failed
            perror( "fgets for input file failed" );
            fclose( pFile );
            for( int j=0; j<numInput; j++ )
            {
                free( input[j] );
                free( output[j] );
            }
            free( input );
            free( output );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, fgets successful

        char * offset = NULL;
        if( NULL != (offset = strstr( tempInput, "\n" )) )
        { // then newline found
            *offset = '\0';
        }

        if( NULL == (input[i] = strdup(tempInput) ) )
        { // then strdup failed
            perror( "strdup for input line failed" );
            fclose( pFile );
            for( int j=0; j<numInput; j++ )
            {
                free( input[j] );
                free( output[j] );
            }
            free( input );
            free( output );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        //printf("\n%s", input[i]);
    } // end for

    /* Close file and clear screen */
    fclose(pFile);
    system("CLS");

    /* Call converter and display result */
    printf("-------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("\nPostfix expression evaluation:\n");
    for(i = 0; i < numInput; ++i)
    {
        printf("input = %s", input[i]); /* i = 2 Printf SUCCESS */
        *output[i] = evaluatePost(input[i]); /* i = 2 CRASH HERE */
        /* I added a check at the top most of the evaluatePost(), program did not get to there */
        //printf("\nCase %d: %s\nResult:%.2f\n", i + 1, input[i], *output[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("-------------------------------------------------------\n");

    for( int j=0; j<numInput; j++ )
    {
        free( input[j] );
        free( output[j] );
    }
    free( input );
    free( output );
} // end function: processPostfixExp
```

Comment: Note:  there is a logic error in my answer:  each of the pointers in 'output' needs to be the recipient of a malloc( sizeof(double) ).    That is also probably what is wrong that is causing the runtime crash.

Comment: Wow, thank you for all the effort! I'm learning your code now, potentially many questions to be asked since the code looks more mature.